# va_start() modifies stack

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

It is said that a call to `va_start()` must be followed by the call to `va_end()` because `va_start()` (always?) disturbs the stack.

Can anybody explain me how does a call to `va_start()` modify the stack and how this modification helps to get the variadic arguments.

Comment: Duplicate of [What exactly is va\_end for? Is it always necessary to call it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587128/what-exactly-is-va-end-for-is-it-always-necessary-to-call-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *may* modify the stack. It may do anything, or nothing. You don't know. Whatever it may or may not do is undone by `va_end()`. That's why you have to call it. What it actually does, if anything, depends on the compiler and the processor architecture. There isn't a single answer.

Comment: And of course what it actually does in any specific compiler is visible in the macro definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each call to `va_start` must be matched by a `va_end`. I don't think it's necessary to know the implementation detail.

> #### C11 §7.16.1 Variable argument list access macros
>
> The `va_start` and `va_arg` macros described in this subclause shall be implemented as macros, not functions. It is unspecified whether `va_copy` and `va_end` are macros or identifiers declared with external linkage. If a macro definition is suppressed in order to
>   access an actual function, or a program defines an external identifier with the same name,
>   the behavior is undefined. **Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function.**

It's the same in C++.